# FGLRX display issue

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, fglrx

I want to use the proprietary fglrx driver from AMD, but the display reacts like this:

- Picture is 10px thick on top of the screen, width normal
- The cursor shows normally
- Works normally only after removing driver (`apt-get purge "fglrx*"`)

I tried with GDM and lightDM, they react the same.

Also, using the open-source AMD driver, I just cannot use my AMD graphics 
card with `vga_switcheroo` by `echo DDIS > switch` even though `vgaswitcheroo` exists. The screen simply turns black and I cannot return to console with Ctrl+Alt+F1

Specs:

> AMD Radeon R5 M230 hybrid with Intel Graphics
>
> Intel Core i5-6400 with 16G RAM
>
> 1920x1080 HDMI display
>
> HP 550-108nf - unchanged motherboard/config/BIOS
>
> Kubuntu 14.04 LTS "Trusty Tahr" with Linux 3.19.0-33 generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at the official documentation on the ubuntu website? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD